# Create a customized path address (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

Goal:
I want to achieve the path address, as string, of the application created in Visual studio 2010. The path is from unit (c or d unit) to the name of the application.

Problem:
I can't create a customized path address in runtime. I don't want a full path address  that is from unit to the name of the picture.

--No to this path address
"D:\work\Modul3\Assignment3\Assignment3\bin\Debug\logotyp_vp_final.jpg"

--Yes, requested path
"D:\work\Modul3\Assignment3"

Please remember that this application and its name of the application and the address can be changed from time to time.

```
namespace Assignment3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for FlightForm.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FlightForm : Window
    {

        public delegate void TakeOffHandler(object source, TakeOffEventArgs e);
        public delegate void ChangeHandler(object source, ChangeRouteEventArgs e);

        public event TakeOffHandler TakeOffEvent;
        public event ChangeHandler ChangeEvent;


        public FlightForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Title = "Flight ";

            cmbStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            btnLand.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            string fullPath;
            fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("logotyp_vp_final.jpg");

            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

            image.BeginInit();
            image.UriSource = new Uri(fullPath);
            image.EndInit();

            image1.Source = image;

            System.Windows.Shapes.Path path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();




        }



        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            cmbStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btnLand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btnStart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            TakeOffEvent(this, new TakeOffEventArgs("a", "b", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            ChangeEvent(this, new ChangeRouteEventArgs("aa", "bb", "cc"));


        }




    }
}
```

---

```
namespace Assignment3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ControlTower : Window
    {
        public ControlTower()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private FlightForm myFlightForm;


        private void btnSendNextAirplane_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myFlightForm = new FlightForm();

            myFlightForm.TakeOffEvent += new FlightForm.TakeOffHandler(PrintOutTakeOff);
            myFlightForm.ChangeEvent += new FlightForm.ChangeHandler(PrintOutChange);
            myFlightForm.Show();

        }




        public void PrintOutTakeOff(object source, TakeOffEventArgs e)
        {

            lstDisplay.Items.Add(new { FlightCode = e.FlightCode, Status = e.Status, Time = e.Time });





        }


        public void PrintOutChange(object source, ChangeRouteEventArgs e)
        {
            string test = e.FlightCode + e.Status + e.Time;

            MessageBox.Show(test);
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path of where the application is executing from:

```
string localPath = new Uri( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase ).LocalPath;
string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName( localPath );
```

**edit**
It sounds like you are attempting to access images outside of your project. As this may work in your sandbox environment, a better practice is to include the images as a part of your project and access them as an embedded resource.

Here's a good read to get you started: [Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

**Walk-through of adding an image as an embedded resource**

Add the file to your project, typically something along the lines of:

```
+solution
  +project
    +Resources  <-- this is Visual Studio's default folder name for resources
      +SomeDirectory
        -logotyp_vp_final.jpg
```

Then:

1. go to your project's properties
2. click to the resources tab on the left side
3. select the `images` resource on the top nav bar.
4. select to add a resource > add existing file. Browse to the file you just put into your project and select to add it.

The file will now show up under your Resources tab of your project's properties. Change the name of your file in the Resources tab to be more meaningful.

Now that the file is an embedded resource of your project, you can access it by the following in code:

```
var MyFile = Properties.Resources.logotyp_vp_final
```

Comment: I get this result:
local path = "D:\\Work\\Modul3\\Assignment3\\Assignment3\\bin\\Debug\\Assignment3.EXE"

currentDirectory = "D:\\Work\\Modul3\\Assignment3\\Assignment3\\bin\\Debug"

Is it a standard to retrieve the address "bin\\Debug"?
My requested address is to get "D:\\Work\\Modul3\\Assignment3" only.

Comment: If you are trying to access the path to the image in your example, `logotyp_vp_final.jpg`, then the image should be a part of the project and not located elsewhere. When you include the image as part of your project, you then have several options to access the image, i.e., an embedded resource or just copy to output directory. And yes, the result you received is the expected result because that is the location the application is executing from.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("..\\..\\logotyp_vp_final.jpg");
```